# C++ & OpenCV assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on application where I needed the following MATLAB code switch in opencv.
This is my code in MATLAB:

```
HSV = imread(k);
S=size(HSV)
x = zeros(3,S(1)*S(2));
k=1;
for i = 1:S(1)
  for j = 1:S(2)
    x(1,k)=i;
    x(2,k)=j; 
    x(3,k)=HSV(i,j,1); %H
    x(4,k)=HSV(i,j,2); %S 
    k=k+1;
  end
end
```

And this is my code in OpenCV, but I think it's wrong:

```
IplImage* img;
img = cvLoadImage("---");

CvMat* x = cvCreateMat(4, img->width*img->height, CV_8UC3);
int k = 1;
for (int h = 1; h <= img->height; h++)
 {
  for (int w = 1; w <= img->width; w++)
  {
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*x, int, 1, k) = h; 
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*x, int, 2, k) = w;
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*x, int, 3, k) = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, h, 3 * w); //H
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*x, int, 4, k) = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, h, 3 * w + 1); //S 
    k = k + 1;
  }
}
```

I get error like this:
**Assertion failed: (unsigned)(4) < (unsigned)(k) && (unsigned)(k) < (unsigned)(*x).cols**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab has 1 based indices and C has 0 based indices - all your for loops and the 1-4 on the left-hand CV_MAT_ELEMs need to go from 0 to length-1.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I corrected mistake but now I get this exception:
First-chance exception at 0x010A6ADD in openCV.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01082000.
Unhandled exception at 0x010A6ADD in openCV.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01082000.

Comment: Did you fix int k = 1 to int k = 0?  With a debugger or print statement you could find what the values of h, w, and k are before the access violation, compare them to width and height.

Comment: Yes, and int's in CV_MAT_ELEMs  switch to uchar. Now everything works. Thank you very much.